# Codeigniter: Twilio browser to browser calling

Tags: twilio

I implemented twilio browser to browser call communication in my codeigniter application but getting error in invalid application sid.
please help anybody.

```
$accountSid = 'ACd628e9947394f6b5d6ca26fad6e34e4f';
$authToken  = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$appSid     = 'CNf384950e8c91c5d78d2512bef7d6dd22';
$clientName = 'XXXXXX';
if (isset($_REQUEST['client'])) {
    $clientName = 9953731934;
}
$capability = new Services_Twilio_Capability($accountSid, $authToken);
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($appSid);
$capability->allowClientIncoming($clientName);
$token = $capability->generateToken();
?>
```

Comment: Do you have your application sid set correctly? Can you share the code where you generate the access token? Thanks!

Comment: $accountSid = 'ACd628e9947394f6b5d6ca26fad6e34e4f';
$authToken  = '7fd0327f7ea3c90524d96b35b072eed2';
// put your Twilio Application Sid here
$appSid     = 'CNf384950e8c91c5d78d2512bef7d6dd22';
// put your default Twilio Client name here
$clientName = 'Pramod';
if (isset($_REQUEST['client'])) {
    $clientName = 9953731934;
}$capability = new Services_Twilio_Capability($accountSid, $authToken);
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($appSid);
$capability->allowClientIncoming($clientName);
$token = $capability->generateToken();?>

Comment: I am not at a computer right now, so I can't give too much detail. However, the Sid you are supplying there does not appear to an App Sid. App SIDs will always start AP and yours is CN. Take a look in your Twilio account and find the TwiML apps section in the dashboard and that should get you the right SID.

Comment: Thanks for giving idea to get correct sid, issue resolved but browser to browser call not getting. Please let me know that browser to browser call is possible or not, not getting anywhere either in youtube.

Comment: Browser to browser calls are possible. Have you tried following the quick start guide to Twilio Client? https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client